# T-SQL Grammar Parser Rule Mutually Left-Recursive With Itself

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I'm actually just extracting a portion of a T-SQL grammar (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4). Specifically, the portion that deals with the `WHERE`-clause, minus any sub-query logic. Unfortunately, it appears that

`expression
    : primitive_expression
    | function_call
    | expression COLLATE id
    | case_expression
    | full_column_name
    | bracket_expression
    | unary_operator_expression
    | expression op=(ASTERSIK | SLASH_F | P_SIGN) expression
    | expression op=(PLUS | HYPHEN | AMPERSAND | CARET | PIPE | (PIPE PIPE)) expression
    | expression comparison_operator expression
    | expression assignment_operator expression
    | over_clause
    ;`

is left-recursive with itself. I'm not sure why I would be getting the error and the whole project doesn't.

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message? When you say that `expression` is "left-recursive with itself" does that mean the set in the error message is just `[expression]`?

Comment: Strip this rule further to a minimal case which shows the described behavior. It could be that one of the referenced rules is causing the trouble.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. I'll try commenting out lines and adding them back.